# What are the differences between Transport Security and Message Authentication over SSL?

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, wsit, transport-security

What are the differences between Metro WSIT's `Transport Security` and `Message Authentication over SSL`?

[Transport Security](http://metro.java.net/guide/Security_Mechanisms.html#ahicx):

> The Transport Security mechanism protects your application during transport using SSL for authentication and confidentiality.

[Message Authentication over SSL](http://metro.java.net/guide/Security_Mechanisms.html#ahicz):

> The Message Authentication over SSL mechanism attaches a cryptographically secured identity or authentication token with the message and use SSL for confidentiality protection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Authentication refers to the security layer designed to confirm a person's identity (via a username and password, for example).

Transport security refers to the security layer that protects the transmission of information, including authentication credentials (username & password), and any data transmitted during use of the application.

To say it another way - authentication is the "ID check" to make sure you are who you say you are, and transport security is what keeps your transactions a secret that is shared only with you, and the server and/or service you are interacting with.